# Best method for adding your script to the window object?

Tags: javascript, window

I've been seeing a familiar pattern in JavaScript/jQuery plugin development (Modernizr uses this first example), by which the functions are nicely wrapped in an IIFE and are globally defined on the *window* object. I am asking is if it's a good idea to make your plugins/scripts accessible globally by doing the following:

```
window.myPluginName = (function (window, document, undefined) {
  // Plugin logic
})(window, document);
```

I ask this because some scripts/plugins need accessing in the DOM where they're called, or elsewhere in a document/file. Inside the plugins I also see this sometimes:

```
(function (window, document, undefined) {
  window.myPluginName = function () {
    // Plugin logic
  }
})(window, document);
```

And even this:

```
(function (window, document, undefined) {
  var myPluginName = function () {
    // Plugin logic
  }
  window.myPluginName = myPluginName;
})(window, document);
```

I am really intrigued as to the differences behind the setups, and if someone with more experience than I would be kind enough to provide some advice on which is best to use for development. Thank you!

Comment: This question ends up a nice, concise summary of the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** Use the one that makes the most sense to you.

**Longer answer:** The only difference is *where* the assignment takes place, but functionality-wise they are all equivalent. None of them has any advantage or disadvantage over the other.

<del>*Note:* As it stands, the last two wouldn't work because `window` is undefined inside the function. But I assume that you'd actually pass the `window` object as argument to the IIFE.</del>

Comment: Thanks Felix, yes my mistake I wrote the close part incorrectly, I've updated the question. Just changed it to pass in the right parameters.

Comment: Of course in the first example, the IIFE would also have to return a function, which would then be assigned to `window.myPluginName`.

Comment: By 'return a function' do you mean so that you'd be able initialise it in the DOM by doing myPluginName(); etc.?

Comment: Well, you assign a function to `window.myPluginName` in the other examples, e.g. `window.myPluginName = function () { // Plugin logic }`, so for all of them to be equivalent, the first would return the function, since the assignment takes place outside the IIFE, not inside.

Comment: Thanks Felix. So how exactly would you 'return' it, and what purpose would you be returning it for? Appreciate the help.

Comment: Just like you return any other value. `return function() { // Plugin logic };` or `var myPluginName = function () { // Plugin logic }; return myPluginName;`. The purpose is the same as in the other cases: So that you can call the plugin with `window.myPluginName()` afterwards.